# Is it possible to trim JSON object in response using Jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, trim, jsonresponse

JSON response returns an object with the following value.

2019-03-20T14:51:30.579+0000

I want to ignore the **.579+0000** part for my validation. How can I trim it from the actual value so that I get:

**2019-03-20T14:51:30**

Comment: take the string and use sub string function with logic to remove the unwanted character .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend parsing the object value as a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), this way you will have possibility to convert it to whatever format you like.

Given you have the following JSON response:

```
{
  "someObject": "2019-03-20T14:51:30.579+0000"
}
```

You can do the transformation as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def originalDate = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).someObject
   log.info("Original date: " + originalDate)
   vars.put("myDate", Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", originalDate).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
   log.info("Converted date: " + vars.get("myDate"))
   ```

   you will need to amend this `someObject` bit with the path to the JSON attribute holding this date. Once done you should be able to access the "trimmed" data as `${myDate}` where required.

   [image]

References:

- [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Dates](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-dates.html)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you. This helped! I have been trying in Java using BeanShell PostProcessor but was unsuccessful.